# how to align the label on x axis for float bar chart and how to make plot option for float bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

```js
<script>
    //Flot Bar Chart
    $(function() {
        var ticks = [[0, "Incoming Call (<?='PLAN_INCOMCALL'?>)"], [1, "Outgoing Call (<?='OUTGNG_CALL'?>)"], [2, "Receive SMS (<?='PLAN_INSMS'?>)"], [3, "Sent SMS (<?='PLAN_OUTSMS'?>)"], [4, "Receive Mail (<?='PLAN_INEMAIL'?>)"], [5, "Sent Mail (<?='PLAN_OUTEMAIL'?>)"], [6, "Database Size(MB)"]
];
        var barOptions = {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.5,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                            opacity: 0.8
                        }, {
                            opacity: 0.8
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
  //tickLength: 0,
  ticks: ticks,
 // min: -0.0, 
  max: 6.5,
 labelWidth: -50
},
            colors: ["#1ab394"],
            grid: {
                color: "#999999",
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                tickColor: "#D4D4D4",
                borderWidth:0
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                      //  format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: true,
            tooltipOpts: {
                content: "x: %x, y: %y"
            }
        };
        var barData = {
            label: "bar",
            data: [
                [0, <?php echo $incoming_count; ?>],
                [1, <?php echo $outgoing_count; ?>],
                [2, <?php echo $sms_received_count; ?>],
                [3, <?php echo $sms_sent_count; ?>],
                [4, <?php echo $mail_received_count; ?>],
                [5, <?php echo $mail_sent_count; ?>],
                [6, <?php echo $db_size_mb; ?>]
            ]
        };
        $.plot($("#bar-chart-usage"), [barData], barOptions);
    }); 
</script>
```

[image: Here in this image the x-axis lable is not in proper manner.]

Here i am trying to give the proper x-axis label for float bar chart but it is not coming properly because text size is too long and i need to give the plot options for float bar chart. how to resolve that one. can anyone please help me and i have mentioned the script.